# Use GREP in Indesign to replace PAIRS of typographer's (curly) quotation marks

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep

**Current format:**

“This is a quoted speech, which said ‘another quoted speech’ is best.”

“However, what about their ‘discussion’s speech’?”

**Intended format:**

‘This is a quoted speech, which said “another quoted speech” is best.’

‘However, what about their “discussion’s speech”?’

**Question:**

Currently, I'm using the find–replace to search for `single left quotation mark`, replacing it with a unique symbol (like ^), and then *manually* replace the ending single right quotation mark with ^ again. Then I replace all double quotes with single quotes and ^ with double quotes. The reason for this is to leave *apostrophes* untouched.

What I want is a GREP way of finding the pairs of single quotation marks, excluding apostrophes, and replacing them with ^.

What I have tried is: `‘.+?’`, which mostly helps but will also detects the apostrophes as a closing quotation mark. I also need to use brackets in the GREP so that I can make Indesign leave the text in between the quotation marks untouched, like so, `(‘)(.+)(?’)` so that the replace field can say `^$2^`.

I would really appreciate any help here.

Comment: I can't really see a way to do this. The apostrophe is in your case the exact same character as the single right quotation mark so InDesign can't distinguish between them. If you for example choose another kind of single quotes and replace `'` with `'` (the same character) InDesign will also change the apostrophes. An apostrophe right between two letters is a special case you could search for, but it could also be in the end of words ending with s (or an s sound) which is indistinguishable from a single right quotation mark after a word ending with s.

Comment: @Wolff I will not do a replace all. I will manually check each instance. So, can you create a GREP that make ID ignore apostrophes appearing between two letters and solves my problem?

Comment: Ah OK, maybe. How about doing it the other way around? I mean finding the apostrophes instead and semi-manually replace them with some unique character first to protect them?

Comment: @Wolff No. There will be a lot more apostrophes appearing in regular paragraphs and just a few appearing in speeches. So, I'd like to tackles the quotation marks only.

Comment: Are the single quotes only ever present within a set of double quotes?

Comment: @Wolff Yes, a pair of singles always in a pair of doubles. BTW, as we are discussion, I'm trying out another way: Left double quotes followed by characters followed by single left quote. And replace that. That's easy, but doing it with the right single and double quotes is a task.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117202/discussion-between-wolff-and-lwtbp).